Why does Nessim steal Balthazar's key in Justine?
A significant event in Lawrence Durrell's Justine is Balthazar's losing the key used to wind up the watch he has inherited from his father. The unnamed narrator comes upon him searching for the key in evident distress:

We had met before, it is true, but glancingly; and would have perhaps passed each other with a nod had not his agitation made him stop me and take my arm. "Ah! you can help me!" he cried, taking me by the arm. "Please help me."
 Durrell, Lawrence. Justine. 1957, rev. 1962. The Alexandra Quartet pp. 13–203. With a new introduction by Jan Morris. London: Faber and Faber, 2012. p. 80.

The narrator does help look for the key, but the search is fruitless. Later in the novel, we learn that Nessim has stolen this key:

"I simply cannot think how this came into my possession" he said, blushing deeply and holding it up for her to see. It was the little watch-key whose loss had caused Balthazar so much concern. Justine stared at it and then at her husband with a somewhat startled air. "Where was it?" she said.
     "In my stud-box."
     Justine went on with her toilette at a slower pace, looking curiously at her husband who for his part went on studying his own features with the same deliberate rational scrutiny. "I must find a way of returning it to him. Perhaps he dropped it at a meeting. But the strange thing is...." He sighed again. "I don't remember." It was clear to them both that he had stolen it.
ibid., p. 143, ellipses in original.

Why does Nessim steal this watch-key? He is one of the wealthiest men in Alexandria and does not need to steal to get by. There is also no suggestion that he is a kleptomaniac generally. The stress of Justine's unfaithfulness and of his plan to kill Capodistria do cause him to lose his mind, but the theft of the watch-key occurs much earlier in the action of the novel, before there is any indication that Nessim is beginning to go mad. This makes it hard to put this action down to incipient insanity, so I'm wondering what his motivation is. The theft of the key also appears to be a loose end in the novel generally, seemingly unconnected to the thread of the narrative, so I find this entire incident puzzling.
